# Can I make all the contents of a GameObject transparent? (Unity3D 2017.3)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an ARCore app (that shouldn't matter, should it?) that has the model you're placing visible at the center of the screen before you place it. These models can be changed by the user.

The effect I'm trying to get is to have the model that you see before you place it 'ghosted'/translucent. What I would ideally like is having an empty `GameObject` (right now named GhostWrapper) that is a parent of the Ghost, and have everything inside GhostWrapper be translucent. This is because the Ghost model can change with user input, and the Ghost is then instantiated on the plane when the users wants to place it:

```
public void SetPlaceableModel(GameObject newModel)
{
    PlaceableModel = newModel;
    var pos = (Ghost != null) ? Ghost.transform.position : FirstPersonCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2f, Screen.height / 2f, -100f));
    var rot = (Ghost != null) ? Ghost.transform.rotation : Quaternion.identity;
    Destroy(Ghost);
    Ghost = Instantiate(PlaceableModel, pos, rot, GhostWrapper.transform);
}
```

I haven't been able to get the GhostWrapper to work, so the below is what I've tried to do directly to the Ghost, but I would prefer if I can have, essentially, the GhostWrapper cause everything inside it to **appear to be** translucent (it doesn't have to force its children to be transparent, but make them look like it).

I have Google'd it quite a bit, and have tried the ways suggested in the top results but almost all seem to be a variation of "get the `MeshRenderer` and set its `.material.color` to a transparent", and that doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried setting the material on my model to use different shaders and setting the colour alpha way down, but none of that seems to be working ([all the answers I've seen appear to be from 2009-2014](https://forum.unity.com/threads/setting-a-gameobject-to-half-visible.47809/), so maybe they're just out-of-date?). I've also tried what the [Unity documentation says](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterAlbedoColor.html) to no avail.

I've thought about having the GhostWrapper be an actual box model that contains the Ghost and manipulating it to make the items inside appear transparent, but since the models can be vastly different shapes/sizes, and the user can move close to them, they could just move inside the box and it would lose the effect.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Note:** the models I'm using have the `Unit/Texture` shader. I am very open to changing that if I can get it to work, but I have changed it to several others, including using `Standard` and changing the `Render Mode` to `Fade` and `Transparent`. Still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify the transparency of the *Unit/Texture* shader because there is no property in that shader that allows you to do so. One way to do this with the *Unit/Texture* shader is to get the base texture property, modify it with one of the `Texture2D.SetPixelXXX` functions and set the alpha to whatever you want. This is slow and unnecessary. Go this route only if you **must** use the *Unit/Texture* shader.

Use the *Standard* shader for this. Below are the steps when using the *Standard* shader.

**1**.Change the material *Shader* to *Standard*

**2**.Change the material's *Rendering Mode* to Fade

You can also do this from code with:

```
void changeMaterialModeToFadeMode(Renderer rd)
{
    rd.material.SetFloat("_Mode", 2);
    rd.material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
    rd.material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
    rd.material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
    rd.material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
    rd.material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
    rd.material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
    rd.material.renderQueue = 3000;
}
```

**3**.Finally, this is how to change the alpha:

```
GameObject ghost = ....;
Renderer ghostRenderer = ghost.GetComponent<Renderer>();

//Get current Color
Color meshColor = ghostRenderer.material.color;

//Set Alpha
const float alpha = 0.5f;
meshColor.a = alpha;

//Apply the new color to the material
ghostRenderer.material.color = meshColor;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll test this out. I'm assuming this is on the actual Ghost model, and not the GhostWrapper, correct? Do you know if there's a way to have the GhostWrapper object be what is 'ghosting' the model (as that would be preferred) i.e. tossing a shader on an empty `GameObject` probably doesn't make sense, but for the sake of an example, that? Or can I do something with layers to make everything on a specific layer translucent? My apologies, I'm still quite new to Unity/game dev and don't know some of the ins-and-outs.

Comment: I don't know what GhostWrapper  is. Is it a GameObject or a script? Anyways, the code in this answer is used to change a transparent of **any** 3D model. In my example, the `ghost` variable is the target 3D model you want to change the alpha. Notice that it is not initialized in my answer. You can do that with the `GameObject.Find` function. Something like this: `ghost = GameObject.Find("Name of Ghost")`. If you are already instantiating the ghost then use the `Ghost` variable in your question.

Comment: My apologies for not making that clear. The `GhostWrapper` is an *empty GameObject* I created in the Unity3D Hierarchy. It is not a model itself, *it is the Transform Parent* of `Ghost`. I am asking about transparency on a wrapping object because when I use `Instantiate(Ghost)` to have an exact copy of the ghosted model. If the Ghost were transparent, I would have to `Instantiate` the model, reset the transparency of the copy, then attach it to the ARCore plane... doing that every time the user makes a copy. Instead, I would prefer a different way of making the Ghost ***appear*** transparent.

Comment: Also, I have been testing your code out, and it does not seem to be making the model transparent... or perhaps the camera is not showing the object as transparent. I'm beginning to think that Google's ARCore objects (world, camera, etc) are causing the problems with seeing the transparency effect. I'll mark this as the answer, though, since no one else has provided one for my case, and this will likely work elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: I did not test with Google's ARCore. Please create a non VR project and test this code to see if it works. I want to know if your problem has something to do with Google's ARCore .